# Building Phaser game reference error: window not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know there are a lot of similar questions frequently. Trying to learn how to build simple game using Phaser framework.

Did it in Visual Code with Live Server extension and it works perfectly.
Can also open the project in Brackets and it's Live preview also works perfectly.

I can't get it to work out of Sublime 3. More importantly, I can't get it to work if I try to load it to a cloud server (like AWS Cloud9). There may be other problems, but these seem to stick on this snippet of code of game.js file.
I have the script reference to that file in my index.html near the bottom of the body section.

```js
// setup game when the web page loads
window.onload = function () {
  game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update, render: render });
  }
```

Have tried using nodejs http server and run node game.js

I'd appreciate some insight as to why this is happening when the game loads and plays perfectly from the Visual Code Live Server and Brackets Live preview. Have spent hours trying to figure this out, and I'm honestly baffled.

Comment: Are you trying to run that code on the server-side?

Comment: window doesn't exist in a node environment